# aspose.word just reads a little content of my doc file

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to get the content of my world file using aspose.net using this code :

```
 Document doc = new Document(@"D:\a.docx");

          // Create an object that inherits from the DocumentVisitor class.
          MyDocToTxtWriter myConverter = new MyDocToTxtWriter();


          doc.Accept(myConverter);


          System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:/a.txt", myConverter.GetText());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

My class defined in above code :

```
public class MyDocToTxtWriter : DocumentVisitor
  {
      public MyDocToTxtWriter()
      {
          mIsSkipText = false;
          mBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the plain text of the document that was accumulated by the visitor.
      /// </summary>
      public string GetText()
      {
          return mBuilder.ToString();
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Called when a Run node is encountered in the document.
      /// </summary>
      public override VisitorAction VisitRun(Run run)
      {
          AppendText(run.Text);

          // Let the visitor continue visiting other nodes.
          return VisitorAction.Continue;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Called when a FieldStart node is encountered in the document.
      /// </summary>
      public override VisitorAction VisitFieldStart(FieldStart fieldStart)
      {
          // In Microsoft Word, a field code (such as "MERGEFIELD FieldName") follows
          // after a field start character. We want to skip field codes and output field 
          // result only, therefore we use a flag to suspend the output while inside a field code.
          //
          // Note this is a very simplistic implementation and will not work very well
          // if you have nested fields in a document. 
          mIsSkipText = true;

          return VisitorAction.Continue;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Called when a FieldSeparator node is encountered in the document.
      /// </summary>
      public override VisitorAction VisitFieldSeparator(FieldSeparator fieldSeparator)
      {
          // Once reached a field separator node, we enable the output because we are
          // now entering the field result nodes.
          mIsSkipText = false;

          return VisitorAction.Continue;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Called when a FieldEnd node is encountered in the document.
      /// </summary>
      public override VisitorAction VisitFieldEnd(FieldEnd fieldEnd)
      {
          // Make sure we enable the output when reached a field end because some fields
          // do not have field separator and do not have field result.
          mIsSkipText = false;

          return VisitorAction.Continue;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Called when visiting of a Paragraph node is ended in the document.
      /// </summary>
      public override VisitorAction VisitParagraphEnd(Paragraph paragraph)
      {
          // When outputting to plain text we output Cr+Lf characters.
          AppendText(ControlChar.CrLf);

          return VisitorAction.Continue;
      }

      public override VisitorAction VisitBodyStart(Body body)
      {
          // We can detect beginning and end of all composite nodes such as Section, Body, 
          // Table, Paragraph etc and provide custom handling for them.
          mBuilder.Append("*** Body Started ***\r\n");

          return VisitorAction.Continue;
      }

      public override VisitorAction VisitBodyEnd(Body body)
      {
          mBuilder.Append("*** Body Ended ***\r\n");
          return VisitorAction.Continue;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Called when a HeaderFooter node is encountered in the document.
      /// </summary>
      public override VisitorAction VisitHeaderFooterStart(HeaderFooter headerFooter)
      {
          // Returning this value from a visitor method causes visiting of this
          // node to stop and move on to visiting the next sibling node.
          // The net effect in this example is that the text of headers and footers
          // is not included in the resulting output.
          return VisitorAction.SkipThisNode;
      }


      /// <summary>
      /// Adds text to the current output. Honours the enabled/disabled output flag.
      /// </summary>
      private void AppendText(string text)
      {
          if (!mIsSkipText)
              mBuilder.Append(text);
      }

      private readonly StringBuilder mBuilder;
      private bool mIsSkipText;
  }
```

When i run this code ,just a little of content is extracted not all of it .
why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to iterate through every paragraph like this:

```
Document doc = new Document(@"D:\a.docx");
var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
var mBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var paragraphs = builder.Document.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph, true).ToArray().ToList();
paragraphs.ForEach(
    x =>
        {
            ((Paragraph)x).Runs.ToArray().ToList().ForEach(y => mBuilder.Append(y.Text));
            mBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:/a.txt", mBuilder.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Where should i put this code ,could you please give me more information

Comment: In .tolist() i have this error Error 1 'Aspose.Words.NodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Aspose.Words.NodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\ehsan\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 51 28 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: Add _System.Collections.Generic_ and _System.Linq_ in your usings

Comment: It was before in the using

Comment: Sorry, it was missing a _ToArray()_ befor _ToList()_. I updated the answer.

Comment: I get this error in the end of the file :This document was truncated here because it was created using Aspose.Words in Evaluation Mode.

Comment: It's because your using a TRIAL version of Aspose. Use either a valid licence file or ask Aspose to give you complete licence for 30 days here => http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx) API, you can easily convert your Word document to TXT format by using the following simple code

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"a.docx");
TxtSaveOptions opts = new TxtSaveOptions();
doc.Save(MyDir + @"a.txt", opts);
```

Another way that you can use to get text representation of whole Word document is as follows:

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"a.docx");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MyDir + @"a.txt", doc.ToString(SaveFormat.Text));
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.